# EFProf .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: entity-framework-5

I recently started using EF5 with .NET Framework 4.5, I wish to use Entity Framework Profiler, 
but when I try to initialize it, I get an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

To note I have referenced the System.Data.Entity assembly.. maybe I have to setup some 
assembly binding redirect in app.config?
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, in the same situation:

Uninstall Nuget Package: Entity Framework Profiler (I proved to install EFProf from NuGet)
Uninstall all instances of Entity Framework Profiler in Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs

Download EFprof from HinernatingRhinos webpage. Unzip in any folder 
Add reference in VisualStudio project to HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll in that folder

Start EFProf.exe and execute the VisualStudio solution

That´s all